# Minecraft Unknown Username or Password

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I try to sign in on Minecraft and it keeps on saying "Unknown Password or Username." And when I try to reset my password, the user name says "Player Not Found." even though I put in the correct name. Why is this happening?

Comment: try using your E-mail where your username goes

Answer (score 0):

Put your email in. When it asks for username simply write the email you registered with. Simple as that.